# Excel VBA: Paste problems

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I have tried a variety of ways to do this paste, but none of them are working. I am extremely new to programming, so I need some help with understanding why I keep getting either error 1004 or 5. I don't even understand what these errors mean.

```
Cells(hotcell).Copy
Cells.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
```

or ...Paste, ...PasteSpecial = xlpasteall, ...pastespecial Paste:= xlpasteall, Range(Cells("B" & i)).paste, Range("B" & i).paste,  and so on as above.

I'm at a total loss. Everything else in the program is working just fine. I just can't get it to paste my copied values into the desired cells (all offset by a certain number of columns, but in the same row). Help and explanation both appreciated.

*Edit* Thanks to BOTH of the answers I recieved, I was able to solve my problem. I really couldn't find a good answer anywhere I looked. Thank you!

The solution I used was one of the simplest:

```
rng.Offset(0, 1) = rng.Text
```

Thanks again to the posters who answered, and the ones who commented. I was making it far too difficult.

Comment: Welcome! This is not an answer, just a comment: often beginners try with copy and paste when a simpler `Cells(R1, C1).Value = Cells(R2, C2).Value` would do the job better and faster. Would that work for you?

Comment: When you use `Cells` you refer to the entire `Range` of a sheet and there is no way you can use `Offset` in it because there is nowhere to offset to. So you will get error `1004`. To know ways on how to copy and paste, refer to BK201's post. It should get you started.

Comment: Also i'm curious whats the value of `hotcell` in your code. `Cells` i think accept numeric argument. If the value of `hotcel` is not a numeric value, you'll get `error 5`. see my post for the complete explanation

Comment: Thanks so much! hotcell was defined as a string, since it is a letter. I tried to get help from my other half, but out of the dozen or so languages he knows, VB isn't important enough for his work. LOL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this kind of problem so I'll try to list some of the ones I use.

**No-paste approach**

```
Sub CP1()
    'This basically just transfers the value without fuss.
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A1")
    Rng.Offset(0,1) = Rng.Value
End Sub
```

**Simple paste approach**

```
Sub CP2()
    'This copies a cell exactly as it is.
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A1")
    Rng.Copy Rng.Offset(0,1) 'Read: Copy Rng to Rng.Offset(0,1).
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**Special paste approach**

```
Sub CP3()
    'This copies the format only.
    Dim sRng As Range, tRng As Range
    Set sRng = Range("A1")
    Set tRng = sRng.Offset(0, 1)
    sRng.Copy
    tRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Try determining from the three above which it is you want and modify accordingly. ;)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Explanation:

```
Cells.Offset(0,1).PasteSpecial
```

This will give `Error 1004` since `Cells` refer to the entire sheet range and there is no way for you to offset it.

```
Cells(hotcell).Copy
```

This will give you the `Error 5` if the value of `hotcell` is not numeric.
I think `Cells` only accepts numeric argument if you used above syntax.

**How to use cells:** (Excel 2007 and up versions)

1.Define R,C syntax:Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber)

```
Cells(1,1) 'refers to Range("A1")
Cells(1,2) 'refers to Range("B1")
Cells(2,1) 'refers to Range("A2")
```

2.Use a number only

```
Cells(1) 'refers to Range("A1")
Cells(2) 'refers to RAnge("B1") and so on
Cells(16385) 'refers to Range("A2")
```

3.Using Cells only

```
Cells.Copy 'copies the whole range in a sheet
Cells.Resize(1,1).Copy 'copies Range("A1")
Cells.Resize(1,1).Offset(0,1).Copy 'copies Range("B1")
Cells.Resize(2,1).Copy 'copies Range("A1:A2")
```

4.Using numbers and letters (This only works on *Cells(RowNum, ColNum)* syntax)

```
Cells(1, "A").Copy 'obviously copies A1
Cells(1, "A").Resize(2).Copy 'copies A1:A2
```

Now, how to copy and paste.
Suppose you want to copy A1:A5 and paste to the next column which is B.

```
Cells.Resize(5,1).Copy Cells.Resize(5,1).Offset(0,1)
```

The above will work because you `Resize` the `Cells` first before you do the `Offset`.
The values of A1:A5 will now be copied to B1:B5.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the info! It really has helped a ton.