# Extract year from a date and paste in next column

Tags: vba, date, excel, copy-paste

So I'm looking at a massive report at the moment and we get one in weekly and we want a macro to automate it.
So one of the columns has numerous dates from 2012 to 2015 in it.
I need to search for the 2014 dates and then from there put 2014 into the column directly on the right of it
My code so far:

```
Sub Engagament_Hiring_Dates()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    For i = 2070 To 4000
        If Year(BDi) = "2014" Then
            Cells(i, 57) = "2014"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry about the code. couldn't get it to look right and it auto formatted it

Comment: No worries, fixed that. Btw, what does `BDi` refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are in Column BD try this:

```
For i = 2070 To 4000
    If Year(Cells(i, "BD")) = 2014 Then
        Cells(i, 57) = "2014" 'or simply 2014
    End If
Next i
```

`Year Function` returns an `Integer`, so you need to compare it to a number and not a string. 
 This will work provided your values in Column BD are valid dates.

Also, you might want to check below on how to use `Cells Property`:

[Using Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485791/excel-vba-paste-problems/20487279#20487279)